Redirect all requests from subdomain to another subdomain including API requests with body and headers (ASP.NET MVC on IIS)
I have an application hosted in IIS with using ASP.NET MVC 5.
In this project there are pages with classic MVC pattern, but it also has API endpoints (ASP.NET Web API).
I want to change subdomain of the website to another, and redirect all requests (API requests and page view requests) without losing request bodies, headers, credentials.
I want to redirect request with all parameters and headers from old.example.com to new.example.com
I tried to use IIS HTTPRedirect module, but I am losing the HTTP request bodies for API requests after redirection.
Here is the web.config  addition that I make to redirect, but it doesn't work for Web API requests, the request body is not transferred to the new subdomain:
<httpRedirect enabled="true" 
     destination="https://new.example.com$S$Q" 
     exactDestination="true" childOnly="false" 
     httpResponseStatus="Temporary" />

How can I solve this issue?

Short version: based on the documentation you need to add an attribute: httpResponseStatus='Temporary'.
Fuller version: there are four different redirect responses that can be returned. Between them they cover:

Temporary or Permenant
Redirect to GET or repeat the request

You want the client to repeat the same request on a new URL, so therefore you need to return a 307 Temporary Redirect response. The default with the httpRedirect is a 302 Found response which tells the client to do a GET request with the new URL.
Note: if the client does not handle a 307 response there is nothing you can do purely on the server: there is a client bug.
PS. if you want to change the subdomain then I'm surprised you do not want a permeant redirect (which should cause the client to remember the change permanently, but likely an API client will require manual intervention, but for bookmarks/favourites should work).
